# how do I log throwable in Log4Net using XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j layout?

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

My Log4Net config looks like this:

```
  <appender name="MainLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${log4net_log_file_name}"/>
    <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="1"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="1MB"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j">
      <locationInfo value="true" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="MemoryAppender" type="log4net.Appender.MemoryAppender" >
    <onlyFixPartialEventData value="true" />
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

We're logging exceptions like so:

```
 private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LastChanceHandler));

        private void LogException(Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Fatal("Unhandled exception", ex);
        }
```

While we are logging errors I never see the Throwable node in the log.  The current layout is used because we convert the XML to DTOs and display them in a UI.

I've not found anything to explain why Throwable is not being set and stored in the log.  Any ideas(I'm considering making my dev box throwable.  Out the window)?

Here's an error from my log:

```
<log4j:event logger="Hsbc.Ice.Shell.ViewModels.ShellViewModel" timestamp="1353076754456" level="ERROR" thread="1"><log4j:message>14 modules did not terminated in a timely manner : TradingCockpitModule,AuthenticationModule,ConfigurationModule,EntitlementsModule,Hsbc.Ice.CreditServices,EncryptionModule,ReportsModule,DiagnosticsModule,InterProcessCommunication,Layout,Logging,PersistenceModule,StorageModule,ICEExplorerManagerServiceModule</log4j:message><log4j:properties><log4j:data name="log4net:UserName" value="HBEU\steveget" /><log4j:data name="log4net:Identity" value="HBEU\steveget" /><log4j:data name="log4jmachinename" value="E8262XDZW4LZKEC" /><log4j:data name="log4japp" value="Hsbc.Ice.Shell.exe" /><log4j:data name="log4net:HostName" value="E8262XDZW4LZKEC" /></log4j:properties><log4j:locationInfo class="Hsbc.Ice.Shell.ViewModels.ShellViewModel" method="&lt;.ctor&gt;b__3" file="d:\CreditFlow\Tools\Hudson\data\jobs\Credit Shell\workspace\src\Shell\Hsbc.Ice.Shell\ViewModels\ShellViewModel.cs" line="107" /></log4j:event>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample line from the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [log4j documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html):

> throwable: Used to output the Throwable trace that has been bound to the
>   LoggingEvent, by default this will output the full trace as one would
>   normally find by a call to Throwable.printStackTrace().

Throwable is [a Java class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) which consequently isn't available in .Net: perhaps an exception stack trace could be substituted, but it hasn't been implemented.

Comment: Is there an equivalent I can use in .Net?  Should I be using this particular layout or is there a better one I could use?

Comment: Any [pattern layout](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html) that includes `exception` will work

Answer (score 1):

Just replace;

```
     private void LogException(Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Fatal("Unhandled exception", ex);
    }
```

with;

```
    private void LogException(Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Fatal("Unhandled exception:" + ex.ToString(), ex);
    }
```

You can also use `ex.StackTrace()` to get the information.

If you want the entire stack trace in .NET

There is no throwable configuration in .NET (or at least I can't find anything about it in the docs), searches only yield Java results which makes sense because there is no `throwable` in C# like in Java.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the answers I decided to try something based on Stuart Dunkeld's answer, above (awarded him the answer, I've put this here for completeness).

Basically, I created a custom Layout that inherited from and overrode the existing layout xml formatter:

The important bit in the overridden method is:

```
    if (exceptionString!=null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(exceptionString.StackTrace))
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("log4j:throwable");
        Transform.WriteEscapedXmlString(writer, exceptionString.StackTrace, InvalidCharReplacement);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
```

For completeness, here's the whole class.  This allows us to catch the stack trace of an error as well as it's message:

```
   public class Log4NetErrorLogger : XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j
    {
        private static readonly DateTime Date1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        protected override void FormatXml(XmlWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            if (loggingEvent.LookupProperty("log4net:HostName") != null &&
                loggingEvent.LookupProperty("log4jmachinename") == null)
            {
                loggingEvent.GetProperties()["log4jmachinename"] = loggingEvent.LookupProperty("log4net:HostName");
            }
            if (loggingEvent.LookupProperty("log4japp") == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(loggingEvent.Domain))
            {
                loggingEvent.GetProperties()["log4japp"] = loggingEvent.Domain;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loggingEvent.Identity) &&
                loggingEvent.LookupProperty("log4net:Identity") == null)
            {
                loggingEvent.GetProperties()["log4net:Identity"] = loggingEvent.Identity;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loggingEvent.UserName) &&
                loggingEvent.LookupProperty("log4net:UserName") == null)
            {
                loggingEvent.GetProperties()["log4net:UserName"] = loggingEvent.UserName;
            }
            writer.WriteStartElement("log4j:event");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("logger", loggingEvent.LoggerName);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("timestamp",
                                        XmlConvert.ToString(
                                            (long)
                                            (loggingEvent.TimeStamp.ToUniversalTime() - Date1970)
                                                .TotalMilliseconds));
            writer.WriteAttributeString("level", loggingEvent.Level.DisplayName);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("thread", loggingEvent.ThreadName);
            writer.WriteStartElement("log4j:message");
            Transform.WriteEscapedXmlString(writer, loggingEvent.RenderedMessage, InvalidCharReplacement);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            object obj = loggingEvent.LookupProperty("NDC");
            if (obj != null)
            {
                string text = loggingEvent.Repository.RendererMap.FindAndRender(obj);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement("log4j:NDC");
                    Transform.WriteEscapedXmlString(writer, text, InvalidCharReplacement);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
            }
            PropertiesDictionary properties = loggingEvent.GetProperties();
            if (properties.Count > 0)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("log4j:properties");
                foreach (DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in properties)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement("log4j:data");
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("name", (string) dictionaryEntry.Key);
                    string text = loggingEvent.Repository.RendererMap.FindAndRender(dictionaryEntry.Value);
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("value", text);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
            var exceptionString = loggingEvent.ExceptionObject;
            if (exceptionString!=null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(exceptionString.StackTrace))
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("log4j:throwable");
                Transform.WriteEscapedXmlString(writer, exceptionString.StackTrace, InvalidCharReplacement);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
            if (LocationInfo)
            {
                LocationInfo locationInformation = loggingEvent.LocationInformation;
                writer.WriteStartElement("log4j:locationInfo");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("class", locationInformation.ClassName);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("method", locationInformation.MethodName);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("file", locationInformation.FileName);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("line", locationInformation.LineNumber);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
```